# Как добавить товар в opencart через sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

Есть конструктор футболок cosuv.ru

Работает через `iframe`, и есть api для того, чтобы сделать следующее:

Товар, который создается в конструкторе и добавляется в корзину.

Но сейчас работает немного иначе: создан один товар в самом магазине, и когда в конструкторе нажимаем кнопку "заказать" и этот товар добавляется в корзину, то есть не фотография товара, и сумма, которую выдает конструктор, не подставляется - все время одна картинка в корзине и одна сумма, отличающая от конструктора.

Теперь задача такая нужно сделать так, чтобы конструктор отправлял запрос sql, который добавит новый товар с ценой и своей фотографией, после чего он добавится в корзину, а на самом сайте его не будет видно.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сделать наоборот. Из конструктора данные пусть попадают в корзину, а при нажатии на кнопку Заказ отправляются в базу данных.

Данные из конструктора можно получать ajax запросом из его API.

Задавайте вопросы, если непонятно будет.

Comment: дело в том что мы пытались это сделать но как сделать так что бы они добавлялись в корзину это не возможно. Если у вас есть варианты как этом можно реализовать мы готовы заплатить. Помогите нам пожалуйста.

Comment: Сейчас загружен - потому конкретное решение под Ваше веб-приложение сделать в ближайшее время не получится. Но могу вечерком посмотреть API и накидать прототип. Дайте, пожалуйста, знать если вопрос еще актуален.